# Como instalar modulo youtube-dl en Node Js

Tags: javascript, python, nodejs

No me deja instalar el modulo de 'youtube-dl' en Node JS por una versión con Python, no entiendo muy bien realmente. Hace unos días instale Python pero no sabía que eso influía. Antes de instalar Python podía instalar el modulo 'youtube-dl' sin ningun problema. La verdad no se si el problema sea Python
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El mensaje de error te marca que el paquete `youtube-dl` está obsoleto y te dice cuál paquete lo reemplaza. Intenta instalar el nuevo paquete y evita usar paquetes obsoletos. No creo que esto tenga que ver con la versión de Python, a menos que usaras la versión 2.x y hayas actualizado a la 3.x. Creo que tiene que ver más con la versión de Node y de NPM. Saludos

Comment: Es un error bastante raro el que muestras. Aparentemente parece que ha fallado la condición de que la versión de python sea >=2, lo que no tiene sentido ya que todas las versiones de python son mayores o iguales a 2. Tal vez lo que ocurre es que no está encontrando python? Qué sucede si en esa misma línea de comandos pones `python --version`?